# On brower back button app `init` method not called

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am showing and hinding a HTML tag by setting variable as `true` or `false`. It works fine, but when a user clicks on the back button of the browser, the method is not triggered. In my route my init look like :

```
init(){
    this.controllerFor('auth-page').set('naviTab', true );
    console.log('init called')
},
```

It works if the page is refreshed, but not by using the browsers back or forward buttons. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost be sure to write: this._super(...arguments), when overriding init (https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/init?anchor=init)

For back and forward events look at activate and deactive events for a route https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/events?anchor=activate